# Accesing Azure MSSQL server from Ubuntu and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, ubuntu, azure

After solving several initial errors I was able to connect to the server. My problem is that I can't seem to access the tables.

Here is the freetds.conf file:

```
[azure]
host = name.database.windows.net
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
database = databasename
```

And here is my PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
# Older FreeTDS installations need the FREETDSCONF Environment variable
putenv('FREETDSCONF=/etc/freetds.conf');
# Current release of FreeTDS uses the FREETDS environment variable. So we set both to be sure
putenv('FREETDS=/etc/freetds.conf');

$server = 'azure';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username@name', 'password');

if (!$link) {
    die('<br/><br/>Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
else {

$query_result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables');

echo "<pre>";
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query_result)){
    print_r($row).'<br/>';
}
echo "</pre>";

mssql_free_result($query_result);
mssql_close($link);
}
```

This is showing me the following on the browser:

```
Array
(
[0] => master
[TABLE_CATALOG] => master
[1] => dbo
[TABLE_SCHEMA] => dbo
[2] => slo_service_dimensions
[TABLE_NAME] => slo_service_dimensions
[3] => VIEW
[TABLE_TYPE] => VIEW
)
Array
(
[0] => master
[TABLE_CATALOG] => master
[1] => dbo
[TABLE_SCHEMA] => dbo
[2] => slo_dimension_settings
[TABLE_NAME] => slo_dimension_settings
[3] => VIEW
[TABLE_TYPE] => VIEW
)
```

and many more. But nothing about my actual tables. Now if I change the PHP to this:

```
$result = mssql_query('select Email from Profile');
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
echo $row["Email"] .'<br/>';
```

I get the following in the browser:

```
Warning: mssql_query(): message: Invalid object name 'Profile'. (severity 16) in file.php on line 23
Warning: mssql_query(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 16) in file.php on line 23
Warning: mssql_query(): Query failed in file.php on line 23
Warning: mssql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in file.php on line 25
```

The same happens if I change the query to:

```
$result = mssql_query('select Email from dbo.Profile');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Invalid object name 'Profile'" indicates that the connection is being made and that the login was successful.  Make sure that the user you are logging in as has proper rights to the Profile table and not just the server.  You may need to add the user to a datareader role.